# Turn off tracing for web jobs that inherit my config

Tags: c#, azure, web-config, trace

I am enabling tracing on my web app (hosted in Azure). This is the content I added into the web.config file:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="file" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="trace.log"/>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Cache">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Http">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.WebSockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Http" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.WebSockets" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="System.Net"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="network.log"
      />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

My app also has 6 web jobs that run in the background. These jobs have their own "app.config" files attached to each one, but they also inherit settings from the parent web app (web.config). This means that each of those 6 web jobs sill enable tracing as well. But I do not want the 6 web jobs to enable tracing. I only want the parent web app processes to enable tracing. Is there a way to disable the tracing in my 6 web jobs? Is there a flag or switch that I can add to each of the app.config files that will turn off the tracing for those individual apps? Something like this:

**app.config:**

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace enabled="false">
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Open the `Web.config` file for your webjobs.

2.Add a new attribute `writeToDiagnosticsTrace` to the trace element under `<system.web>`, and then set `writeToDiagnosticsTrace` to false.

```
<system.web>
      <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true"/>
</system.web>
```

The [writeToDiagnosticsTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.tracesection.writetodiagnosticstrace(v=vs.110).aspx) gets or set a value indicating whether the message emitted through the page trace are forwarded to an instance of the [Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class.

For more details you could refer to this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Also, you could turn off Dashboard logging. Those additional blob containers that you mentioned are the storage for all the Dashboard analytics logs.

To disable that, you can set `config.DashboardConnectionString=null` in Program. That will completely disable all Dashboard logging.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not seem to work. The web jobs have `app.config` instead of `web.config`. And the web jobs did not like the `writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true"` attribute. I got runtime errors on all of them when I added this attribute.